# an ide for php to access remote server in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, ide, sftp

i have recently start working in ubuntu and i have to work on remote servers. so I have to work on the vi editor , which is good but then i decided to work on the ide , so i installed netbeans , now i am able to login to remote server with the "sftp", but here is a problem , the remote server does not allow the root access at first time , so i have to login with a demo account and then have to use "su - " to get the access as root .

so in netbeans i am not able to switch user after login. is there any way.

so my question is this is it possible for me to work on any ide which provide me facility to use itself , in this situation or not ?

Comment: You `sftp` and then `su`.  Wow!

Comment: @devnull His means that he tried sftp with normal user account on netbeans, While root permission only available when he shell login to remote server with normal user and the use su to become root, This way he can not complete his work through IDE.

Comment: thanks !! Kuldeep for explaining my point.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `sshfs` to map the server folder in a place within your machine, then you can use your IDE directly in that folder, forgetting about permissions.

To mount:
`sshfs user@server.com:/path/to/code/folder /home/user/local/folder/`

To unmount:
`fusermount -u /home/user/local/folder/`